# JavaScript Function To See If Any Text Is Within An HTML Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating an extremely basic javascript version of tic tac toe. I have already set up the board utilizing a table and assigning borders appropriately.

When the player makes a move an X is placed within the box, and when the computer goes an O.

However my issue is trying to decide if the cell has been "used" meaning that there already exists an X or O within.

Is there a function in javascript which can check for contents within an HTML element or can anyone think of another way to do this? I considered using an array of 9, holding x or o and checking this way, but I ran into the issue of figuring out how to pass the cell number to that function to update the array.

I'm new to javascript so if either of these possibilities exist please let me know or if you have any suggestions of your own!

Comment: Are you using any JavaScript framework, like jQuery?

Comment: Both are possible, do you have a preference?

Comment: @mrtsherman which ever you think would be faster. I know its simple checking and (I believe) shouldn't take too much time, but with the checking of an element several times over I feel as though it may take longer than an array and just checking the values within. Thoguhts?

Comment: @djdy Yes I'm utilizing jQuery. This is handling my click operation on the cells currently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.textContent) and [`innerText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533899%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the text of an element.

**Example:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="hello-container">Hello, World!</p>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var el = document.getElementById('hello-container');
            var text = el.textContent || el.innerText || '';
            alert('The text is: ' + text);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Explanation:**

Since IE8- uses `innerText` and Firefox uses `textContent` (with other browsers choosing either one side or both), you need to check both properties. We make use of JavaScript's logical or operator `||` to check both properties in one line. `text = el.textContent || el.innerText` will store `el.textContent` in `text` if there is a `textContent` property. If there is not a `textContent` property (or if `textContent` is the empty string or just whitespace), then it will try to store `innerText` in the `text` variable. Finally, we use `|| ''` to set it to the empty string if neither `textContent` nor `innerText` could be found *****.

***** This is only necessary if `textContent` was the empty string/whitespace and `innerText` did not exist, in which case both would be falsey. Rather than let `text` be `undefined`, we store the empty string `''` instead.

---

If you would like to check to see if HTML is in an element rather than text (this would be helpful if you are using image elements for your X and O) you can use [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.innerHTML). This is standard for all browsers!

Comment: is it possible to do something like this: `if(!(e1.textContent || e1.innertext))` to check if there is already something there?

Comment: Yes, of course! That will work perfectly. Note, however that `innerText` must have a capital T.

Answer (score 2):

the best way would be to use a 2-dimension array :

```
            var tictactoe = [["","",""],["","",""],["","",""]]
```

then use

```
            if(tictactoe[row][col] == "")
                tictactoe[row][col] = "X" //(or "O", you decide)
```

and use a separate function for drawing

Comment: There's no need to initialise the arrays with empty strings, so `if(!tictactoe[row][col])`. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Similar to David…

I built a tic tac toe game using an array to hold the moves, then have the display based on the array (separate the game logic from the display). That way you don't care about what's in a cell.

Anyway, you can do:

```
if (element.textContent || element.innerText) {
  // there is some text content
}
```

However, there may be whitespace in the element that results in false positives. Or the X and O might be an image element, whatever.

Answer (score 0):

I think since tic-tac-toe is so simple, you could just use a single array.

```
var board = new Array(9);

//Board layout:
// [0][1][2]
// [3][4][5]
// [6][7][8]

//Win if any of these combinations are present
//012, 036, 048, 147, 246, 258, 345, 678
```

Then just loop through `board` and figure out if it has a value of `X` or `O` and do some simple checks to see if they have 3 in a row.

```
var x = [], o = [];
var winner = 'Game in Progress';
for(var i in board){
    if(board.hasOwnProperty(i)){
      if(board[i] == 'X') 
        x[i] = true;
      else if(board[i] == 'O')
        o[i] = true;
      if(i == 8) winner = 'Cat Game';
    }
}

if((x[0] && x[1] && x[2]) || (x[0] && x[3] && x[6]) ||
   (x[0] && x[4] && x[8]) || (x[1] && x[4] && x[7]) ||
   (x[2] && x[4] && x[6]) || (x[2] && x[5] && x[8]) ||
   (x[3] && x[4] && x[5]) || (x[6] && x[7] && x[8])){
     winner = 'X is the Winner';
}

if(winner != 'X is the Winner')
if((o[0] && o[1] && o[2]) || (o[0] && o[3] && o[6]) ||
   (o[0] && o[4] && o[8]) || (o[1] && o[4] && o[7]) ||
   (o[2] && o[4] && o[6]) || (o[2] && o[5] && o[8]) ||
   (o[3] && o[4] && o[5]) || (o[6] && o[7] && o[8])){
     winner = 'O is the Winner';
}
```

I wrote up [**some of the code**](http://jsfiddle.net/yYpZ6/) that you would need to make a tic-tac-toe game so you can understand better. What will be left for you is to display who's turn it is, make it so when a player clicks on a box (during their turn) their symbol gets added to that box (if it is empty), and resetting of the game. Good luck. :)